# Match/find and replace all series of tab characters with one tab

Tags: replace, find, search-replace, filetype-csv

I have a tsv file that has the header separated by tabs but each row is separated by one or more tabs. The parser/viewer I'd like to use doesn't understand that the values are separated by a series of tabs. It expects there to be just one tab between values.

How can I use Vim or another program to find and replace all series of tabs (of variable length) with just one tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackexchange! :)

You can do this by selecting the line(s) you are interesting in and using the following substitution command: `s/\t\+/\t/g`

The structure of this command is the following: `s/pattern/substitution/g`

- `pattern` is `\t\+`, which means one tab or more
- `substitution` is `\t`, which means one tab
- ending with `/g` means that you will do this substitution multiple times one a single line, as many times as there are matches on your `pattern`

Hope this helps!

Comment: "pattern is \t\+, which means one tab or more" - this was what I was missing. Good to know. Thank you! I actually realized that the tsv file just has a lot of NA/null values and I didn't actually need to do this. Still though, this will help me in the future. I really appreciate it!